# Move file from FTP to remote, but having special char password issue

Tags: batch-file

I am writing 1 script to move file from ftp to remote.

its running fine while doing in command prompt, but when i am writing batch script, its not executing properly, 
first giving me error that user is not logged in, might be coz i have special char in my password.
code are below, its a urgent issue.. looking for quick answer
tried it to give pswd in diff. file. tried it with ^^ output is correct but only in echo

my password is  **^xinPS032**

```
echo ^^caret^^

@Echo Off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set _FTPServerName=ftp.us.benfieldgroup.com
Set _UserName=FtpTemp0013
Set _Password>ftpcmd.dat
echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat
Set _LocalFolder=FtpTemp0013
Set _RemoteFolder=D:\Informatica\9.5.0\server\infa_shared\BWParam
Set _Filename=*.zip
Set _ScriptFile=scrip
:: Create script
>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo ftp %_FTPServerName%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo %_UserName%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo %_Password%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo lcd %_LocalFolder%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo cd %_RemoteFolder%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo binary
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo get %_Filename%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo quit
:: Run script
ftp -s:"%_ScriptFile%"
Del "%_ScriptFile%"
```

error msg

> ftp> ftp ftp.us.benfieldgroup.com
>   Invalid command.
>   ftp> FtpTemp0013
>   Invalid command.
>   ftp> xiPS032Set _LocalFolder=
>   Invalid command.
>   ftp> lcd FtpTemp0013
>   FtpTemp0013: File not found
>   ftp> cd D:\Informatica\9.5.0\server\infa_shared\BWParam
>   Not connected.
>   ftp> binary
>   Not connected.
>   ftp> get *.zip
>   Not connected.
>   ftp> quit

Answer (score 0):

Your first command should be `open`. ftp scripts are intended to be run as if you were typing them directly into an `ftp>` "shell". within that "shell", you initiate a connection with "open", not "ftp", e.g:

```
ftp> ftp ftp.adobe.com
Invalid command.
ftp> open ftp.adobe.com
Connected to ftpgen.wip4.adobe.com.
220-ftp.adobe.com
220-Adobe Systems, Inc.
```